# what is the complex number that satisfy both loci $\lvert z\rvert=4$ and $\lvert z+2\rvert=\lvert z-4\rvert$?

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

I have solved most of the question.  This is my work but I can't seem to find what this part is.  It's supposed to be $1\pm i\sqrt{15}$ but I don't know why.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you

> On a single Argand diagram, sketch the loci $\lvert z\rvert=4$ and $\lvert z+2\rvert=\lvert z-4\rvert$.  Hence determine complex numbers that satisfy both loci, giving your answer in Cartesian form.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use image as question as it is next to impossible to search (especially with a blurry image).

Comment: @user10354138 okay but is my working out okay as I cant really type it?

Comment: Have you determine the locus of $\lvert z+2\rvert=\lvert z-4\rvert$?  It should be pretty obvious once you have a nice description.

Comment: @user10354138 I can't follow the working, but the sketch tells me that yes, they have determined this locus.

Comment: @user10354138 i have but i dont know how you get the complex number from it. As I have never solved a question like this before.

Comment: @Theo Bendit z1=-2 ad z2=4 the midpoint is (1,0) with a radius of 4 and gradient of 0.

Comment: @Sara Use Pythagoras's theorem. Draw a radius from $0$ to the point of intersection. That radius has length $4$. The horizontal side of the triangle has length $1$. What does that say about the vertical side? How can you then calculate the other solution?

Comment: @Theo Bendit that gave me √15 how do I get the complex number 1±√15? Ow sorry so the √15 is the y which we substitute into z=x+iy right?

Comment: @Sara The real and complex parts of these points of intersection are the horizontal and vertical displacement of these points from the origin. Both points have horizontal displacement $1$, while the points have vertical displacement $+\sqrt{15}$ and $-\sqrt{15}$. Thus, the solution is $1 \pm \sqrt{15}i$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit thank you really helped me with this problem I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sara You're welcome! It's nice to help out someone who is so responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation: $|z+2|=|z-4|$ is the locus of perpendicular bisector of line segment joining $(-2,0)$ and $(4,0)$. So it is straight line whose equation is: $x=(4-2)/2=1$.

The equation $|z|=4$ represents a circle of radius 4 centered at $(0,0)$.
Put $z=x+iy=1+iy$ in the circle’s equation to get point of intersection.

Comment: I have done this and have the point of intersection if you can see my work but I don't know how to make it the complex number

Comment: @Sara: $|z|=|1+iy|=\sqrt {1+y^2}=4$. Now solve to get $y=\pm \sqrt{15}$. So our unknowns  are $z=x+iy=1+i(\pm \sqrt{15})$.